# How to see model class in H2 database

Tags: java, jpa, h2

I cannot see my tables that I created as model class in h2 database console.

Actually I can access the h2 database (by writing localhost:/h2-console). But I can't see my tables.

Altough I added @Entity annotation, I can not see the table in h2-database.

**Product model class:**

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 * Created by jt on 11/6/15.
 */
@Entity
public class Product implements DomainObject{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String imageUrl;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: All uppercase is perceived as screaming. Avoid doing that.

Comment: And did you get your JPA provider to create that table? Did you look in the LOG of your chosen JPA provider? Did you do any debugging?!

Comment: I used Intellij Idea and I debugged successfully. And when I wrote localhost:8181/u2-console on web browser, I saw login screen of h2 database. And I connected the database but I didn't PRODUCT table. And also I added h2 dependency to pom.xml.

Comment: which doesn't answer the questions. Did you configure your JPA provider (whichever one you are using ... you still haven't said) to GENERATE THE TABLES? What did the LOG of aforementioned JPA provider tell you about the table generation? H2 is not a JPA provider.

Comment: I got hibernate.

Comment: Right, and now tell us the answers to the questions ...

Comment: I can not write logs to here because of too long character. How can I send  the logs to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I corrected my jdbc url for u2 database. Now, I can see my tables(model class) that I created via java.

Comment: And also we should add jdbc url to application.properties file.

Comment: This will be the URL that you did not post in the question, even though people asked about your configuration. Rendering the question of no value to anybody else who comes by here without that info being included in the QUESTION. Suggest that you delete it

Comment: The jdbc url is changeable. the url depend on kid of database. I used h2 database here. I used **jdbc:h2:~/test**  here.